# rewrite rule htaccess - how to get back query sting for usage

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

Is there is a way to get query string back in PHP?

I have:
`http://mywebsite.com/cars/BMW/` `http://mywebsite.com/List.php?categories=/cars/BMW/`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /List.php?categories=$1 [L]
```

I want to capture categories value in PHP .Please note the parameter format '/cars/BMW/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categories=(.*)
RewriteRule .* /List.php?categories=$1 [L]
```

This will capture whatever comes after categories in the query-string and apply it in the rule.

Answer (score 3):

You access the value just like you used to so to get the cars value you would just do this.

`echo $_GET['categories'];`

should echo out

`/cars/BMW`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, access it via `$_GET['categories']`, and use the `explode()` function to separate the parts on the `/`:

```
if (isset($_GET['categories']))
{
  $parts = explode("/", $_GET['categories']);
  $vehicle_type = $parts[0];
  $vehicle_make = $parts[1];

  echo $vehicle_type . " ";
  echo $vehicle_make;
}
```